# Identifing client identity

Tags: asp.net

I just implemented a very simple logging process for my asp.net website. This website is hosted on an IIS on a server on which nobody is logged on. Clients will connect to this website with a local network address. I am logging information on the operations done and on how much time it took. If someone wants to read the log file, he cannot know which operations were run by him since everybody's operations are written at the same place.

I want to add an information to identify the user everytime I log something. I tried accessing HttpContext.Current.User, but this always has a generic identity. I looked in HttpContext.Session too, but did not find anything relevant...

I would like to log the computer name or the username of the user (the one he used to logged into windows), or something else that would help my users identify which operation are theirs. (I could also separate everything in separate log file, but then again I would need something to tell them appart).

Comment: I *think* that if you are on a local intranet, you can enable Windows Authentication for your app and just allow everyone to connect. Then `Current.User` should work.

Comment: You mean <authentication mode="Windows"> in web.config? I just tried it. It worked when debugging in visual studio, but not after deploying. I think when deployed it takes the windows user of the server (which is none...)

Comment: You might have to do a little work with anonymous login. I know I've done this before, but I'm really sorry I don't remember exact details.

Comment: You're going to have to require a login at *some point*. Whether it's Windows, Forms or retinal scan, that's the only guaranteed way to get a reliably unique and persistent identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while, I found a way to get the client's computer name that way.

```
string name =
  System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName.Split('.')[0];
```